# Unique signal extraction from a cumulated signal

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, time-series

I'd like to start off by saying that I am not very experienced at signal processing, so I apologise in advance if I do not explain everything properly the first time.

I would like to analyse the following

*Signal A:*
[image: Signal A]

Signal A is a simplified simulation of an air compressor, with the compressor operating between 140 and 160 PSI **(YELLOW SIGNAL)**. The blue and orange lines indicate that a component that draws air from the compressor is active, which you can notice causes dips in the PSI level.

The following signal represents the amount of PSI drawn by the components, causing the noticed drops in PSI:

*Signal B:*
[image: Components which lower the PSI level]

Signal B is generated by adding two **separate** pulse generators, and fed through an integrator. I would like to analyse Signal A to obtain each individual signal that makes up signal B.

The two pulses that make up signal B are:

1. Off for 14 seconds, on for 1 second, amplitude = 1 PSI
2. Off for 900 seconds, on for 40 seconds, amplitude = 0.5 PSI

I would like some recommendations for what processes to use to achieve this. I have tried wavelets and FFT to no avail so far. I hope to use my findings here to allow me to train a machine learning model to expect drops in air pressure  by X PSI every Y seconds.

**NOTE:** This signal normally has a slight bit of noise, however I removed it for this post. The components turning on are also not exactly periodic in my actual data (reiterating that this is a simulation), however the times are only ever out by 1% at most.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! You say you've tried wavelets. What sort? [Haar wavelets might work well.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet).

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome!

I have tried three wavelets so far, morlet, paul and dog (all CWT). I'll give Haar a shot! I found the issue with the wavelets to be that the sawtooth shape of the wave was too significant and the filter basically smoothed out these smaller signals.